# sbackup fails after Ubuntu upgrade

Tags: 14.04

I was using the package sbackup (Simple Backup) without problems until a few months ago when it suddenly started to fail each time I try to back up with error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'st_size'. I am not 100% sure, but I think this started to happen after I upgraded from Ubuntu 12.04 LTS to 14.04 LTS.

Hope that you can help, thanks, John

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem with permissions for the external drive to which I am backing up, not in principle related to sbackup. Will keep working and submit another question if needed. Thanks and sorry, John